# 502 Bad Gateway:[nginx/1.4.7]

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am configuring django (1.6.5) project with gunicorn and nginx server.Project successfully working with django basic server `python manage.py runserver`.And later i bind an address with gunicorn as `gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001`.And configured in `nginx.conf` file at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.When i restarted nginx server and given request in browser as `localhost:8080` i am getting `502 Bad Gateway`.What is the mistake i am doing

Here is my `nginx.conf` code

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name localhost;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
  }
```

Updated:

In the error log file:`error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;`

i am getting the following;

```
2014/05/29 13:13:08 [crit] 6701#0: *1 connect() to 0.0.0.0:8001 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8001/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have overcome the above problem by placing my current fedora working user name as `nginx` working user.I have find the user at the top of my `nginx.conf` file in the `/etc/nginx` directory.I am currently  working as `user` in linux environment, and replaced the user name `nginx` with `user` in the `nginx.conf` file. That's it my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently expecting a HTTP (not WSGI) handler on 8001. You can read more about Nginx WSGI configuration here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html

Comment: In the docs it self only he mentioned like the above in this link http://gunicorn.org/#deployment